# Detect mixed language php

Tags: php, regex

i know how to detect only arabic letters by this

```
   $string = " هذه اللغة العربية";
   if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]/', $string)){}else{ // is arabic
```

I knowhow to detect only english letters

```
    $string ="This is english language" ;
   if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]/', $string)) {   // is english
```

BUT if its mixed it detect it as arabic .

```
   $string = "this is عربية" ;
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]/', $string)) { }else { // is arabic
```

What i want is when its mixed then detect it as english NOT arabic  .

AND how to add these symbols also `@`  so when

```
    $string = "@اتااتاتانت" ; // it will be also detected as english
```

Thanks

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]` is **NOT** "only arabic". it's "any English character at the start of the string". `^[^A-Za-z]$` would be "strings with only non-english characters", which MAY be arabic. but `3.14159265` would be "arabic" by that definition.

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote this question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks , its up to the their humor  ,,

Comment: @MarcB sorry its the opposite i made error i will update

Comment: Take a look at http://pcre.org (the regex engine used by PHP). You will find a character class for arabic characters.

Comment: @MarcB this `^[^A-Za-z]$` will detect the mixed string as arabic , which i dont want like that , i need to detect it as english

Comment: @ScooterDaraf: I think all you need is to check if a string contains an ASCII letter: `if (preg_match('~[a-z]~i', $input)) { echo "It is NOT Arabic"; }`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked your solution :) . will i remove my question or you want add your answer and accept it ?

Comment: If you remove too many questions on end you will get banned, I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic, all you need is to check if a string contains an ASCII letter:

```
if (preg_match('~[a-z]~ui', $input)) { 
   echo "It is NOT Arabic"; 
}
```

You do not even use `\p{Arabic}` here.

Comment: To do that this way, you need to use the u modifier, otherwise you will have false positive.

Comment: Sure, that goes without saying.